# Install programs remotely on Windows: psexec + autoit

Tags: installation, deployment, psexec, autoit

I want to install a program remotely, for which I understand there are two options:-

- **Group Policy** (or using other Windows built-in option): The thing is I'm trying to install a distributed system, so group policy doesn't make sense here.
- **PsExec**: it could work well but I have some problems with it: I'm trying to install MySQL and FileZilla FTP Server.

  - for MySQL server: I guess I could work hard and use Orca to understand the properties in MySQL MSI, but with FileZilla it's hopeless since it an .exe and not MSI.
  - That's why I wrote an AutoIt installation script that works well on a local computer but can't be run remotely since PsExec doesn't open a "UI session" but a shell (like SSH in Linux). If I attach it to an existing session (using the `-i` flag) it works, but I can't assume the computer will not be locked on installation.

Deployment is hard, any suggestions?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why exactly doesn't group policy fit here? What do you mean by a distributed system?

Comment: distributed system: Take SETI as an example (I built a small-scale system, but the concept is the same)